# Sending arguments to getter in python: Is this an acceptable solution?

Tags: python, properties, getter, getter-setter

For the sake of discussion, lets say I want to write and read values from a `dictionary` but I want to append some string to the dictionary key.  Instead of having the user do the string manipulation, I want to hide it inside `setter` and `getter` methods.  This works no problem with the Python `setter` method since I can send a list full of information that can be parsed.  It does NOT, however, work with the `getter` method since arguments cannot be sent to `getter`.  I have concocted the workaround shown below where the `getter` returns a function which accepts the arguments and does what I want.  I'm just wondering if this acceptable Python or if I will regret using this approach.

```
class tester(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._dict = {}

    def _set(self,some_list):
        self._dict.update({some_list[0]+'_'+some_list[1]: some_list[2]})

    def _get(self):
        return self._func

    def _func(self,key1,key2):
        keys = key1+'_'+key2
        return self._dict[keys]

    props = property(_get, _set)

a = tester()
value = [1,2,3,4,5]
a.props = ('main_key','sub_key',value)
print(a.props('main_key','sub_key'))
```

I have searched high and low for ways to use `setter` and `getter` that suit my needs, but all I see are people asserting that Python doesn't need them and we should all just be adults and access the attributes directly.  The closest I've found is this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760916), but I find my solution more direct.

Comment: i don't think there is anything per se wrong with this. And since it is nicely encapsulated i don't really see you having any issues with it. Imho its kinda weird to do this though =)

Comment: You could also use `__getitem__` and `__setitem__`

Comment: @Faust: I hate to be too demanding, but could elaborate on your suggestion, or point me to something sort of example?

Comment: @2cynykyl I have answered giving you an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

properties (or any other descriptor) are for computed attributes, that is members that have the *semantic* of an attribute but needs some computation either on set and/or get. By 'semantic of an attribute', I mean it makes sense, from the client's code, to write:

```
something = obj.attribute
```

and / or

```
obj.attribute = something_else
```

As soon as you have to pass arguments to a getter or more than one argument to the setter, it doesn't have an `attribute` semantic, obviously, so you cannot use a computed attribute. The solution is simple: use an explicit getter/setter pair.

The point about getters/setters not being needed in Python is that *for anything that has attribute's semantic* (but not anything else) you can always turn a direct attribute access to a computed one if and when you need it without breaking the client code. That's not your case here obviously.

tl;dr: abusing properties the way you do is not pythonic and you'd be better with explicit getter and setter.

Comment: You could view "more than one argument to a setter" as just passing a single `tuple`-valued argument...

Comment: @EMS : and how do you handle getters needing arguments exactly ?-)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: I currently do use explicit getter and setter, but I was drawn to the clean/consistent syntax of using `property`.  I really appreciate your description of direct vs computed attributes.  If I understand you correctly, then sending arguments to the 'setter' is cheating, which clarifies my confusion about why `getter` was much less flexible than `setter`

Comment: @2cynykyl: the syntax for properties is clear and consistent exactly because it **does one and only thing**. The examples of your code (the way you wanted it to look) were very confusing. So, yes, I upvoted both answers: you should use either custom methods or `__setitem__`.

Comment: Well, a setter (a property or other descriptor's setter that is) do expect one argument of course - the value you want to set your attribute to. A _getter_ should not expect any argument obviously. Also set and get are supposed to be as symetrical as possible - one doesn't expect that after settings an attribute's value to a list or tuple, getting the same attribute returns a callable taking one less argument ;) More seriously: this is legal Python but it's also as unpythonic as possible. Your API should be along the line of `set_value((key1, key2), value) and `get_value((key1, key2))`.

Comment: @EMS : I was talking about about a descriptor's getter of course - but I admit it wasn't necessarily quite clear from the context ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of what you could do using `__getitem__` and `__setitem__`:

```
class tester(object):

    class Subelement(object):
        def __init__(self, obj, key):
            self.obj = obj
            self.key = key

        def __getitem__(self, subkey):
            return self.obj._dict[self.key + '_' + subkey]

        def __setitem__(self, subkey, value):
            self.obj._dict[self.key + '_' + subkey] = value

    def __init__(self):
        self._dict = {}

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return Subelement(self, key)
```